# UINavigationBar back button Title Changes on orientation changes

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin

`UINavigationBar` backButton's Title Changes when orientation changes.

`FirstViewController` title

```
This.Title = "FirstScreenTitle";
```

`SecondViewController` title

```
This.Title = "SecondScreenTitle"
```

When Navigate from `FirstViewController` To `SecondViewController` in portrait mode it shows Navigation back button title  "back".

When changes orientation `SecondViewController` navigation back button title name changes back to `FirstScreenTitle`.

Comment: if u don't mine any keyword `This` is used in iOS

Comment: Correct, the format is self.title

Comment: Where and all you are setting your self.tile = "FirstScreenTitle";

Comment: I am working In Xamarin C# language. self.title = "abcd" its says "The name self does not exist in current context"

Comment: @anubu.karthik  This.Title  is equal to self.Title  Xamarin IOS C#  to Objective-C Xcode respectively

Comment: So, what is your question? Such behavior in iOS occurs due to large length of the title. If you make it shorter, title itself will appear instead of "back" keyword

Comment: @Azat In navigationController when navigate from one window to another window, default it shows back button with title "back",  When changes the orientation to landscape the back button Title Changes to previous Window Screen Title.  In all Cases even orientation changes the second window back button should be "back"

Comment: @kiran, you can set "Back button" property in the storyboard for the navigation item of your first controller

Answer (score 0):

The title of the back button will by default be "Back". Only when you change the `NavigationBar.Title` will the title of the button change to whatever it is you are telling it to be. If you want to have the back button to always have the title "Back", don't alter the `NavigationBar.Title`.